# Recursive loop which returns a value according to a single condition

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have a method that takes as parameter an array of several depth (`group`) and a name as a string (`currentFilterName`)

```
checkFilterValue(group, currentFilterName) {
  group.forEach((element, index) => {
    if (element.children) {
      if (element.name === currentFilterName) {
        this.returnedValue = element.value
      } else {
        this.checkFilterValue(element.children || this.filtersConfig[index + 1], currentFilterName)
      }
    } else {
      if (element.name === currentFilterName) {
        this.returnedValue = element.value
      }
    }
  })
}
```

The depth levels are the `element.children` , being the goal is to return the `element.value`, at each turn if the element has a depth level I first check if `element.name === currentFilterName` if it is the case I would like returned the `element.value` if it is not the case I return the method evening with the next `element.children` if there is otherwise the original tables with the next index `this.filtersConfig [index + 1]`, if the element has no depth I simply check if `element.name === currentFilterName` and I return to `element.value`

The problem I have is that the method is a little verbose, how can we simplify it with an elegant writing?

Comment: What other code is in this object's definition? Is it in `strict` mode? Why do you want to set `returnedValue` this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your code has an issue:

```
this.checkFilterValue(element.children || this.filtersConfig[index + 1], currentFilterName)
```

The `this.filtersConfig[index + 1]` is never called as you check `element.children` first:

```
if (element.children) {
   ...
}
```

Your code doesn't need a `forEach` as a for loop will be better:

```
checkFilterValue(group, currentFilterName) {
  for (let key in group) {
    const { name, value, children } = group[key]
    if (name === currentFilterName) {
      return value
    }

    if (children) {
        let found = this.checkFilterValue(children, currentFilterName)
        if (found) return found
    }
  }

  return null
}
```

By using a for loop you are able to directly return the value if found.

Another issue of your code is you missed to reset `this.returnedValue` doing so you have a bug if you call 2 different searches and the second one doesn't find anything.

Although you didn't share other code, maybe you should do this in another method.

You can see I use the spread operator to make the code much more concise:

```
const { name, value, children } = group[key]
```

and get rid of `element.something`.

Not sure how to handle the part where you call the function with a different set of data, but maybe inside this method is not the right place of doing it.